# Adding OnClickListener error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api

Using eclipse and my phone Api17 is connected as device.
The app will run on my phone ok.

But when i add this bit of code , it does not work ,
eclipse says there is no problem with the code itself ,
no errors etc.

But if i add the code below, i get a white then black screen and it stops working. With this code is does not work , without this code it does work.

Not that it does much anyway but i am just starting off.

```
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter ++;
            total.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter --;
            total.setText("Your total is " + counter);

        }
    });
```

This is my logcat:

```
 03-06 20:23:20.082: W/dalvikvm(28046): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413a9ac8)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.attempt2/com.example.attempt2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at com.example.attempt2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-06 20:23:20.082: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    ... 11 more
```

My code is:

```
 package com.example.attempt2;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.os.Build;

  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//variables
int counter;
Button add , sub;
TextView total;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subbutton);
    total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);



    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter ++;
            total.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter --;
            total.setText("Your total is " + counter);

        }
    });


    // Below is basic code for extra options for api19+
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container,placeholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

    }
```

My xml codes are

activity main

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.attempt2.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment main

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.attempt2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/subbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addbutton"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:text="@string/sub"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not possible. there is something else. post the logs, and the surrounding code.

Comment: where is `add` and `sub` and `counter` and `total` declared?

Comment: Forget the surrounding code, just post the stack trace from logcat.  People will ask for code once we can see where the *real* error is.

Comment: i think you not initialize your widget or use wrong id for those, check that and post more code

Comment: Cant post the surrounding code this is telling me its not written correctly and don't know how to correct. I will post the log errors

Comment: Ok does anyone know how to copy the logcat ?

Comment: Save it to disk selecting the relevant lines and clicking in the floppy icon

Comment: Ok have added that to main part of question

Comment: please post all logcat error, all red area

Comment: what is in line 35 of your code?

Comment: add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: `add` is null, check id of that, did you initialize `add`?

Comment: What do you mean by initialize ? I have linked the add button to the id of the add button in the xml file

Comment: can you post that line?

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

Comment: counter = 0;
  add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
  sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subbutton);
  total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
  

  
  add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: There is the xml part of the link of the add button , and then a couple of variables plus the add variable linked by Id

Comment: please clean your project and test again, did you setContentView this layout?

Comment: Sorry am quite new to java , what is setContentView? I have cleaned the project a couple of times with no result

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: yes, did this widget that you post as comment in this layout?

Comment: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  counter = 0;
  add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
  sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subbutton);
  total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

Comment: this is it in context  , i would post you the entire code but it won't let me , do you have email ?

Comment: please post your code on your question, post `activity_main` layout

Comment: There is all my code in mainActivity.java just below the logcat

Comment: where is `activity_main` layout?

Comment: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.attempt2.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

Comment: just this? so where you put button's and other widget. and please again post everything on your post, hard read on comment

Comment: Ok i will post them all in the question in just a second , I did all my buttons and textview in the "fragment_main.xml" , is that correct to do so ?

Comment: no, is not true, if you want have those on your fragment layout then you need put your code on fragment class, say what you want exactly that i put code for you

Comment: perhaps the code for me to transfer over to activity_main from fragment_main . Will that make it work then ?

Comment: if you want handle your code on your activity, then your widget must be on activity_main layout.

Comment: So i change setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         to         setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
??

Comment: or do i transfer code from fragment main to activity main instead ?

Comment: see my answer, and ask anything on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 way,

first: put your widget on activity_main layout and handle on `MainActivity` class.

second: put your widget on fragment layout and handle on `PlaceholderFragment`.

I post code for first way:

for first way you just need change content of activity_main layout to:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.attempt2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/subbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addbutton"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:text="@string/sub"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: first: put your widget on activity class and handle on there 

I do not understand what a widget it , or how to put on activity class ?

Do you mean , change setcontentview to activity main ?

Comment: It has worked ! , thank you so much Shayan you have been great ! , activity_main is now the same as fragment_main , should i leave it that way or should i put what used to be in activ into frag ?? or just leave it ? thank you so much man

Comment: both same each other because i copy that layout. see 2 way and tell me what you want, you need your button and other on your fragment or on activity_main ?

Comment: It now works now that is on activity main rather than fragment main. , so you didn't change the code ?

Comment: no, i just copy fragment code. i now it's work, now you can change fragment layout to anything that you want

Comment: What will changing the fragment layout actually do , what does fragment_main do ?

Comment: for now, nothing but if you add your FrameLayout to your activity_main layout then you can see result of your change